# I am using pydroid3 and image.show() not working when I'm running it just say program finished

Tags: python, pydroid

I am using pydroid3
I created a folder and running python in that folder because my photo is in that folder
Image.show is not showing anything
When I click on run
It simply says " program finished

from PIL import Image

tf = Image.open("test1.png")

tf.show()

Comment: maybe you want to save the image to a file rather than show it

Comment: It's already saved In folder

Comment: The documentation for `Image.show()` only describes behavior on Unix, MacOS, and Windows.  Apparently there's no default support for Android (although this could be added via the `PIL.ImageShow` module).